# Float CSS Positioning

Tags: css

I am trying to align several images in the same line. I am using `float:left` for this task. The problem is images are big and browser show them in many lines. How can I do to order several html elements in one line, despite of it isn't enough space?

Thanks

Comment: image elements are inline anyway so they shouldn't need to be floated.  Unless you have them inside a block element.  But as you haven't shared any code, we can't help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap a parent div around your images and set `white-space:nowrap;` property to this div.

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="" width="300" height="300" />
</div>

#parent{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qs21wecn/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/FQAjE/1/)

```
 div {
    text-align: justify;
}

div img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i think he means, always one line... even when it doesnt fit